# computing only the diagonal of a matrix product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given symmetric and positive definite matrices
$$    C
    = \begin{pmatrix}
        C_{11} & C_{12} \\
        C_{21} & C_{22}
      \end{pmatrix}
    \in \mathbb{R}^{(p+q)\times(p+q)}
$$
and $H \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$, I want to compute the **diagonal**
of the matrix
$$ A = C_{21} \bigl( C_{11} + H \bigr)^{-1} C_{12}. $$
(This is part of the posterior covariance matrix in a smoothing problem.)  The dimensions $p$ and $q$ are both between $100$ and $1000$.  Is there an efficient algorithm, considering speed and/or memory usage, to get the diagonal?

The best I came up with is the following:

1. Solve $(C_{11} + H)B = C_{12}$ for $B$, using Cholesky decomposition.
2. Compute the element-wise product of $C_{12} = C_{21}^\top$ and $B$.
3. Compute the column sums of the result to get
   $$\sum_j (C_{12})_{ji}B_{ji}
      = \sum_j (C_{21})_{ij} B_{ji}
      = A_{ii}.$$

Is there a better way to exploit the symmetry of the problem?

Comment: @DietrichBurde $C_{11}$ and $H$ are both positive definite, so their sum $C_{11} + H$ must also be positive definite and therefore invertible